# How to properly init jQuery module on React component?

Tags: reactjs

I have parent React component called Sorter. Inside of Sorter I have child component for range slider:

```
<div className="child">
    <rangeSlider props=... />
</div>
```

`<rangeSlider props={...}/>` returns simple input:

```
render() {
    return <input type="text" id={this.props.id} name={this.props.id} value=''/>
}
```

And then I call module initialization via `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    jQuery('#' + this.props.id).ionRangeSlider(config)
}
```

And everything works fine until I actually use range slider. I have callback in `config`, which updates parent (in this case it's Sorter's) state. After that range slider just disappears. I tried to reinit it via `componentDidUpdate()` but it didn't do the trick.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say that your `value=''` is your problem. ionRangeSlider probably emits a change event that React binds to, and when it gets a change, it resets the value back to an empty string. Try removing `value=''` and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @Kyle nope, this way slider gets removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Since I call `<RangeSlider props={...} />` render with new props everytime, it triggers React to update DOM and to run re-render.

From the very beginning we have rendered only a single `<input>` element which has only static attributes that will never change:

```
<input type="text" id={this.props.id} name={this.props.id} value='' readOnly />
```

And ionRangeSlider, when called, prepends it's own DOM elements to this input and after this happens we don't need to interact with this input anyhow.

Thus we don't have to re-render it everytime new props arrives. So I just wrapped input in empty `<div />` and prevented render from being executed:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" id={this.props.id} name={this.props.id} value='' readOnly />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Yet still I don't think it's a good practice to write dummy methods like this that only returns single static value, but as long as my rendered DOM won't change under no circumstances the situation is under control.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-sea-imwpp?fontsize=14

As you can see, it's working fine.

Could you please provide the error message or more details?

Such as :

1. Is the `RangeSlider` has to update when the range changed?
2. How does `Sorter` change its state with the `ionRangeSlider` config?

Thanks.

---

Comment: I did it a bit different. I don't have data I need in Sorter's scope so I pass the function directly into RangeSlider props: `<RangeSlider id={this.state.id} onSliderChange={this.onSliderChange.bind(this)} />`. And then inside `componentDidMount()`: `this.props.onSliderChange(stateToChange)`

Comment: so why is this line `this.props.onSliderChange(stateToChange)`  executed in `componentDidMount()` of `RangeSlider `?  I thought it was the `config.onChange`  function of the `onRangeSlider()`.

Comment: Because I can't pass a function as `<RangeSlider >/` prop. `onChange` has a callback with `data` from ionRangeSlider and I need this data since change parent state is not the only thing I'm trying to to there.